# Using several JS files in StackBlitz with a simple JS-project

Tags: javascript, stackblitz

In [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) it's possible to add another JS file(s) (besides `index.js`) but it seems that only `index.js` is actually being loaded. All the functions defined in other JS files created in the same (root) folder are just `undefined` when I try to call them within the `index.js`. I tried to 'activate' other files via HTML (`<script src='./filename.js'>` tag) but it didn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in index.js:

```
import {func} from './myscript.js';
```

In myscript.js:

```
exports.func = function(){...}
```

Comment: But then how do you use a function described in `myscript.js` inside `index.js` ?

Comment: @CodyBugstein, like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/svelte-imozn2?file=index.js

Comment: Can you also take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898665/how-do-you-load-a-json-in-a-stackblitz-project

Comment: (btw I cannot award bounty for another 21 hours, but I will asap)

Answer (score 4):

I have tried this and worked for me.

In index.js add below statement

```
import "./myscript.js";
```